# When using the IDEA's debugging feature, there is a significant delay when pressing the 'step over' key

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

I go into debug mode with idea and I press step over, the program executes very slowly, usually taking more than ten seconds for a simple logic, and much longer if there are database operations involved. If I use "Force step over", the program immediately goes to the cursor

Comment: Do you have any method breakpoints? They can be slow.

Comment: See also https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544799